# Print the duplicate value

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to check a files containing duplicate data using pandas.

```
Student,"Details"
Joe|"December 2017|chemistry"
Bob|"April 2018|chemistry|Biology"
sam|"December 2018|physics"
```

I want to check any duplicate value in second column(Details),If it has any duplicate value then print the line with all the duplicate value .So here it should be

```
Joe|"December 2017|chemistry"
Bob|"April 2018|chemistry|Biology"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the `Details` columns by '`|`', [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), check if value is [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) index and use max aggregation to create a boolean mask. Use this mask to filter.

```
mask = (df['Details'].str.split('|')
        .explode()
        .duplicated(keep=False)
        .groupby(level=0).max())

df[mask]
```

[out]

```
  Student                       Details
0     Joe       December 2017|chemistry
1     Bob  April 2018|chemistry|Biology
```

Answer (score -1):

the pandas duplicated function should identify your duplicates.

```
pandas.duplicated(subset='Details')
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
def pandas_duplicate_rows(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|')
    duplicate = df.duplicated(subset='Details')
    df2 = df.merge(duplicate, on=['Student'])
    if len(df2.index) == 0:
        print('No content found')
    else:
        print(df2.head())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = 'D:\sample3.psv'
    pandas_duplicate_rows(path)


Im not getting expected output